# Updated column shows wrong data type in view after recreating

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have updated a column(nullable) data type from number(3) to number(8) by first dropping the column then recreating it. There is a view that uses data from this column that still reflects the column as number(3) instead of number(8). I am fairly new to using oracle, I came from SSMS background.

I have tried dropping and recreating the view.  Also tried dropping the view then the column and creating the column then view but view still keeps showing up as number(3).

Comment: It sounds like the view isn't against the table you think. Are they in the same schema, and does the view definition include a schema prefix when it refers to the table? Or a database link? Or perhaps the table name is very subtly different? Please include the DDL for the table and view, including which schema(s) they are in.

Comment: Yes. This was it. There was 2 similar schemas with same view, one had an underscore and other did not. ‍♂️ What was the previous dev thinking 

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to drop a column in this case; you could have just altered it:

```
SQL> create table test (col number(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (123);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace view v_test as select * From test;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_test;

       COL
----------
       123

SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                NUMBER(3)

SQL> alter table test modify col number(8);

Table altered.

SQL> select * from v_test;

       COL
----------
       123

SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                NUMBER(8)

SQL>
```

---

Even if you did it by dropping a column (which was probably a bad idea, as you lost data stored in it), view should automatically reflect datatype change:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col number(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, 123);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace view v_test as select * from test;

View created.

SQL> select * From v_test;

        ID        COL
---------- ----------
         1        123

SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 COL                                                NUMBER(3)    --> number (3)
```

Drop the column and put it back, with modified datatype:

```
SQL> alter table test drop column col;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test add col number(8);

Table altered.
```

Check its datatype: as I said, it is automatically reflected:

```
SQL> desc v_test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 COL                                                NUMBER(8)   --> number (8)

SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID        COL
---------- ----------
         1                       --> COL is empty, though

SQL>
```